# Probability Question with computing integral and finding the constant

Tags: probability, random-variables

The random variable X takes one of the values 1, 2, 3, 4 with probabilities

P(X=i)=ic,  i=1,2,3,4

I need to first find the value of c, and then compute P(2<=X<=3)

Comment: Hint: if $X$ takes no other values then $\sum_{i=1}^4P(X=i)=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of:
$ \sum_{ x\in R_x} P(X=i)$ 
Where $ R_x=(1,2,3,4) $
Which function do we use to compute such probabilities?